# Equivalent Callback function for "$.getJSON("myurl",response);"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$.getJSON( "myurl", response);
```

What would the equivalent callback function version of the above look like? I've tried...

```
$.getJSON("myurl",function(data){
      //manipulate data
      return data;
});
```

but it doesn't appear to produce the same result.

I'm working with [JQuerys AutoSuggest](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) library and attempting to manipulate the response I receive back from my server before sending it on.

Comment: What is the differing behavior that you are seeing?

Comment: when you say not the same result, can you be more specific?  The callback format you use works when I've used it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.getJSON ("myurl", function (data)
{
      // manipulate data

      response (data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you pass data that are sent to the server. In the second case, you pass a success callback. There is no way of making an "equivalent callback version" to the first usage. See [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Answer (score 0):

The callback will be the same but you can manipulate data in different ways, for example:

As you specified two types, look case 1 and 2

case 1:

```
//start and receive callback
function send()
{ 
  var v = $("element").attr("value");
  $.getJSON("page.php",{ v:v }, responseData); 
  return false;
}

//manipulate callback data
function responseData(data)
{
  $("#results").html("Name: " + data.name + "<br/>" + "Lastname: " + data.lastname);
}
```

case 2:

```
$.getJSON ("page.php", function (data)
{
   $("#results").html("Name: " + data.name + "<br/>" + "Lastname: " + data.lastname);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.